# apt-get install without internet

Tags: apt, kali-linux, lvm

i have kali linux that i run like vm.

I want to run command `apt-get install` but i not have a internet access.

witch kind of file linux expect?

how can i put this file on some folder on the kali and the command will search and install from there? (i will download from another computer with internet access and put directly on some folder on this vm)

thanks

Comment: If you have a `.deb` package, you should be able to `apt install /path/to/myniftypackage.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

Better than installing file-by-file, you create a proxy APT server, and configure as a client the VM without Internet access.

In the APT server side:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng
```

On the client side (VM without direct Internet access):

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<IP address or hostname of the apt-cacher server>:3142";
```